# Find all non-latin1 (ISO 8859-1) characters in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, ascii, iso-8859-1

**EDIT WITH NONWORKING ATTEMPT**

I am giving something like this a try, but getting `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
islatin1=[]

for column in DF.columns.values.tolist():
    for row in DF.iterrows():
        for i in row:
            if i:
                if type(i) != bool:
                    if type(i) != float:
                        try: 
                            i.encode(encoding = "latin-1", errors="strict")

                        except:
                            islatin1.append([row['ID'],column, row[column]])
```

CliffNotes - Need to identify any data in my dataframe that isn't latin 1 so I can stop it from going to a finicky database.

Currently I am checking a dataframe for any non-ascii characters by doing:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple—', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.™com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call� now','http://www.reddit.com~|~http://www.youtube.™com~|~http://www.youtube.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com�', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that � could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

def asciifunc(df,column):
    isascii = lambda s: len(s) ==len(s.encode())
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if not isascii(row[column]):
            aascii_list.append([row['ID'],column, row[column]])

aascii_list=[]

for x in DF.columns.values.tolist():
    try:
        asciifunc(DF, x)
    except TypeError:
        continue

Invalid_chars = pd.DataFrame(aascii_list, columns=['ID', 'Bad_Column', 'Bad_Data'])
```

But now I need to find any non-Latin1 (ISO 8859-1) characters. (I have a database that is giving me fits about the characters I pass, so I need to flag any piece of data that exists in my dataframe that has characters that aren't latin1.  (Like: ™, —, �, etc.)

I'm not sure where to go with hunting down these other than maybe a regex that lists all the latin1 characters?

Edit: apparently Wiktor didn't like me tagging regex in the post even though I think it might be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. I know it probably needs some cleanup, or could be applied like Karl suggested. But it works for now.

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple—', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.™com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call� now','http://www.reddit.com~|~http://www.youtube.™com~|~http://www.youtube.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com�', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that � could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

islatin=[]

def latin1(df, column):
    islatin1 = lambda s: bool(s.encode(encoding="latin-1", errors="strict"))
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row[column]:
            try:
                islatin1(row[column])
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                islatin.append([row['ID'],column, row[column]])    


for x in DF.columns.values.tolist():
    try:
        latin1(DF, x)
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        continue

latin_chars = pd.DataFrame(islatin, columns=['ID', 'Bad_Column', 'Bad_Data'])
print(latin_chars)
```